# Group homomorphism yields to monoidal functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoidal-categories, functors

Consider a group $G$. We can get to a monoidal category $\cal G$ with objects being the group elements, tensor product given by group multiplication and just the identity morphisms as morphisms.

Further, let $\cal C$ be a monoidal category.

Assume we have an injective group homomorphism $$G\to\text{Aut}(\cal C)$$ into the group of monoidal autoequivalences of $\cal C$.

How do we get a monoidal functor ${\cal G}\to\text{Aut}(\cal C)$? Here the tensor product on $\text{Aut}(\cal C)$ is given by composition.

Comment: $\text{Aut}(C)$ is a 2-group, not a group. (It can even be upgraded to a 3-group with some effort.)

Comment: Ok, does this help to answer the question? I am not familiar with 2-groups. Is it a group if we assume $\cal C$ to be strict?

Comment: I don't think you're using the monoidal structure on $\mathcal{C}$ if the tensor product in $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{C})$ is just the composition. If that's the case, you already have a monoidal functor (you only need to define further on the arrows, and $\mathcal{G}$ only has identity arrows !). This is monoidal because you start from a morphism so $F(x\otimes y) = F(xy) F(x)F(y) = F(x)\otimes F(y) $

Comment: The monoidal structure of $\cal C$ is important as we want to consider the group of monoidal (!) autoequivalences of $\cal C$, not just the autoequivalences. For what do we need the injectivity of the group homomorphism? And is your functor fulfilling the hexagon diagram?

Comment: You don't have an idea or is my question just a little stupid? :)